# How to not fix OPENSSL version in CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a problem with OpenSSL version when I use my binary file in other environments. When I run

cmake ..
I see this output

```
Found OpenSSL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so (found version "1.0.2g")
```

and when I use this in other environments, where OpenSSL version is different(for example 1.0.2d) I receive this error

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.2: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2g' not found.
```

How to solve this issue

EDIT: This is CMakeList.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(cryptomagic)
include(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake)

set(MBED_TLS_VERSION 2.12.0)

ExternalProject_Add(mbed_tls URL https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls/archive/mbedtls-${MBED_TLS_VERSION}.tar.gz
PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mbed_tls
CMAKE_ARGS -
DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mbed_tls/build
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(mbed_tls install_dir)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR /usr/local/opt/openssl/)

find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
if(OPENSSL_FOUND)
    set(OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE) 
endif()

include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR} src src/include 
${install_dir}/build/include include)
```

Comment: @usr1234567 edit post and add Cmake code

Comment: According to [wiki page](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Versioning), the last letter doesn't affect on binary interface. It is strange that this letter is included into symbol version when packaging OpenSSL for distros. However, you unlikely can overcome this: neither version embedded into you library may be equal both to `1.0.2g` and `1.0.2d`.